# Replace the output row text with another text without updating or inserting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    x.ans, 
    COUNT(*) AS num_ans
FROM 
    ans x, 
    get_fit('5')
GROUP BY 
    x.ans, 
    get_fit.getfit
ORDER BY 
    x.ans ASC;
```

output:

```
  id | num_ans
 ----+---------------
  X  |  5
  Z  |  7
```

But I want to change the X and Z with AName and BName respectively without inserting or updating the tables. How do i do it?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right query for this output? It appears to me that you performed at least minor modifications :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to achieve this, would be [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html) command. Your query could look as follows:

```
SELECT 
    x.ans as original_id,
    CASE WHEN x.ans='X' THEN 'AName'
         WHEN x.ans='Z' THEN 'BName'
         ELSE x.ans
    END as modified_id,
    COUNT(*) AS num_ans
FROM 
    ans x, 
    get_fit('5')
GROUP BY 
    x.ans, get_fit.getfit
ORDER BY 
    x.ans ASC;
```